# Why does Android Bundle use PutInt(String key, int value) but Intent use PutExtra(String key, int value)?

Tags: android, api, android-intent, dictionary, android-bundle

Why aren't the put methods in Android Intent named with a primitive or class suffix such as:

- public Intent putExtra**Int** (String name, int value)?

Bundle put methods have the primitive suffix:

- public void putInt (String key, int value)

Intent, however, has it without the primitive suffix:

- public Intent putExtra (String name, int value)

Wouldn't it be better to have a consistent naming pattern? Does it have anything to do with the fact that Intent's put methods return an Intent for the purpose of "[returning] the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement." If that's the reason, why?

**I know what an overloaded method is. Let me clarify: why is it overloaded for one class but not for the other? The main question: why not have a consistent API?**

Comment: its called function overloading. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html .

Comment: Right, so why do we have overloaded methods for Intent's put but not for Bundle's put?

Comment: You are asking for opinions. This isn't what stackoverflow is for. Everyone you ask will have a different opinion. This isn't a forum to discuss why the Android developers arent' consistent. If you really want an answer to this question, you will need to ask the Android developers, but I don't think you would get anything other than opinions from them either ;-) Nobody is perfect. And APIs are hell to fix after you've released them into the wild.